# JSF bean initializing with faces-config.xml

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans, faces-config

I've a Bean named as Bucket, it has a HashMap. I want to initialize the bean and polulate the HashMap in the faces-config.xml with a property file. How can I do that?

Bean:

```
public class BundleBean {
 private Map<String, String> bundlePropertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
 private String bundleFileName;

 // Setter, getter goes here....
}
```

Property file, named as `bundle.properties`, and it's on the classpath.

```
bucket.id=DL_SERVICE
```

faces-config.xml file :

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>
        Java bean class which have bundle properties.
    </description>
    <managed-bean-name>bundleBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.example.view.bean.BundleBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>bundleFileName</property-name>
        <value>bundle.properties</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

That Map has to have the bucket.id as the key and DL_SERVICE as the value.

Thanks in Advanced~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the properties file is in the same ClassLoader context as `BundleBean`, call a method like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void loadBundle(String bundleFileName, Map<String, String> map)
                                                         throws IOException {
    InputStream in = BundleBean.class.getResourceAsStream(bundleFileName);
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(in);
        ((Map) map).putAll(props);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This is best invoked using the `@PostConstruct` annotation. If that is not an option, call it either in the `bundleFileName` setter or perform a lazy check in the `bundlePropertiesMap` getter.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with spring that has a more advanced dependency injection mechanism.
when you integrate spring with jsf, you can define your jsf bundlebean in the spring context

```
<bean id="injectCollection" class="CollectionInjection">
        <property name="map">
            <map>
                <entry key="someValue">
                    <value>Hello World!</value>
                </entry>
                <entry key="someBean">
                    <ref local="oracle"/>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
```

Comment: But, My requirement is get the values from a property file, not from xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, JSF calls the corresponding setters when initializing the bean. Thus providing a method `public void setBundleFileName(String filename)` should work.

Comment: My problem is with setting the HashMap property, not with the bundleFileName property

Comment: @Kugathasan You could load the file manually at a reasonable point in time (the first access, in your setter etc.). Try using the `Properties` class.